# AngularJS table flickers

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple AngularJS app that shows a table with data on an ng-repeat after the user logins.  I'm having an issue where after logging in, the table briefly shows blank rows and then the actual rows with data. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

This is the controller for the login:

```
  $scope.login = function(user) {
    loginSrvc.login(user).then(function(response) {
      if (response == "authentication failed") {
        $scope.error = true;
        $scope.user = {};
         $location.path("/");
      } else {
        if (response.group_name == "On Site Registration"){
             var data = {
               event: response.zk_event_id,
               group: response.zk_group_id
             };
             $scope.getAvailableCamper(data);

        }
        else if (!response.zk_group_id) {
                   $location.path("/form/" + response.zkp_camper_id);
             }
             else {
             $location.path("/dashboard/" + response.zk_event_id + "/" + response.zk_group_id);
             }
      }

    })
  }


$scope.getAvailableCamper = function(data) {
    dashboardSrvc.fetchGroup(data).then(function(response){
         var findAvailableCamper = _.find(response.data, {status: null});
         console.log("this is find", findAvailableCamper);
         var id = findAvailableCamper.zkp_camper_id;
        $location.path("/onSiteForm/" + id);

    })
  }
```

This is the controller for the table:

```
$scope.campers = function() {
    $scope.camper = loginSrvc.getCampers();
  }

  $scope.campers();

  $scope.fetchCampers = function(id) {
    dashboardSrvc.fetchCampers(id).then(function(response){
        $location.path("/form/" + id);
    })
  }
```

Here's the html code for table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="campers in camper">
            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td>{{campers.name_first}}</td>
            <td>{{campers.name_last}}</td>
            <td><button type="submit" name="submit" ng-click="register(campers)" class="btn btn-success" role="button" ng-hide="campers.status == 'Submitted' "  ng-disabled="!(!!campers.name_first && !!campers.name_last && !!campers.gender && !!campers.city && !!campers.date_of_birth && !!campers.email && !!campers.emergency_cell_phone && !!campers.emergency_contact_first_name && !!campers.emergency_contact_last_name && !!campers.emergency_home_phone && !!campers.relationship_to_camper && !!campers.first_time_flag )">Submit</button> <p ng-show ="campers.status == 'Submitted'" > {{campers.registration_date | date: 'medium'}}

            </p>
            </td>
            <td>{{campers.status}}</td>
            <td>
              <button ng-click="fetchCampers(campers.zkp_camper_id)"  type="submit" name="view" class="btn btn-default" role="button" ng-show="campers.status == 'Submitted' "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
              <button ng-click="fetchCampers(campers.zkp_camper_id)" type="submit" name="edit" class="btn btn-default" role="button" ng-hide="campers.status == 'Submitted' " ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>

  <button type="button" ng-click="setValue(campers.zkp_camper_id)" name="deleteModalLauncher" id="deleteModalLauncher" class="btn btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" ng-hide="campers.status == 'Submitted' " ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>

            </td>
          </tr>
```

I really appreciate the help! Thanks!

Comment: Use something like `ng-show="finishedLoading"` and set `$scope.finishedLoading = true;` inside the `then` of the last async statement

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it's still showing the flicker.

Comment: You could try replacing all interpolations `{{}}` with `ng-bind`. If it still happens, my guess is that it's because of route changes after loading data.

Answer (score 2):

There is a directive to minimize flickering that angular loop does while check bindings and all. it is called ng-cloak and it can be added to any element on your view.

More info : https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-cloak.asp

...

You can also use angularjs event who is fired when content is fully loaded and set a flag ex. loaded = true and then use ng-show with loaded variable.

Controller :

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
   $scope.loaded = true;
});
```

View :

```
<table ng-show="loaded">
  .....
 </table>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've tried both ng-show and ng-cloak and the flicker is still there.